# Can you Auto update branches from the Main trunk?

Tags: dynamic, version-control, tfs, merge

Here is the scenario.

We are developing a product where we have a base product and regional variations for the product. We have all the common code checked into the main trunk while we have created 2 branches (branch_us, branch_uk) for the variations off of the main trunk. There is common code that is constantly being checked into the main trunk and the code that is being checked into branch_uk,branch_us is dependent on the code that is checked into the main trunk. This is being done because we expect more regions to added in future releases and as a result we want to have max reuse as well as thin regional variations layer.

Based on the current strategy, the developer will have to develop locally and then manually check-in the common files into main_trunk and regional variations into branch_uk & branch_us. Then everytime code is checked into the main_trunk, we will have to perform a merge from *main_trunk->branch_uk* & *main_trunk->branch_us* before we can perform a build  for branch_uk & branch_uk (two separate deployments) because of dependency of new code in branch_uk/us branch to the new common code in main_trunk. This model seems extremely painful to think about and unproductive. 
I'm by no means an expert on TFS. Here is what I am seeking opinion on:

***Is there a way TFS can dynamically pull changes into branch_uk/branch_us from the main_trunk without doing a manual merge after every check-in (in the main_trunk)?***



***Do you guys have any other recommendations on the code management process that might be more effective/productive than the current one?*** 


Any thoughts and feedback will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

This seems like a weird architecture to me, but of course I'm coming at it from a position of almost total ignorance, so there might be a compelling reason to approach it that way.

That being said: It sounds to me like you don't have a single application with two regional variations, you have **two separate applications** that share a common ancestor. The short answer to your question is "No". A slightly longer answer is "No, but you could write code to automate it."

A more thoughtful question-answer is "Are you sure centralized version control is the right tool for the job?" It might be more intuitive to use Git for this. What you have are, in effect, a base repository and two forks of that repository. Developers can work against whatever fork makes sense, and if something represents a change that should apply to all localizations, open a pull request to have the change merged into the base repository. This would require more discipline on the part of the developers, since they would have to ensure that their commits are isolated such that they can open a pull request that contains **just** commits that apply to the core platform. Git has powerful but difficult history-rewriting tools that can assist. Or, of course, they could just switch back and forth between working on the core platform, then pulling changes from the core platform back up to the separate repositories. This puts you back to where you started, but Git merges are very fast and shouldn't be a big issue.

Either way, thinking of the localizations are a single application is your mistake.

A non-source control answer might involve changing the application's architecture so that all localizations run off of the same codebase, but with locale-specific functionality expressed in a combination of configuration flags and runtime-discoverable MEF plugins, or making a "core" application platform that runs as an isolated service, and separately developed locale-specific services that express only deviations from the core application platform.